# PHP: If No Rows In Table DO THIS

Tags: php, if-statement

I have some code that cycles through the rows in a MySQL database that looks like this:

```
while($query2=mysql_fetch_array($query))
```

How could I create and IF statement that would check to see if the rows are empty? For example

```
if $NoRowInDB {

echo 'Sorry, try again';

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you mean:

```
if (mysql_num_rows($query2) == 0) {
    echo "No rows found, nothing to print so am exiting";
    exit;
}
```